# J2EE to Java standalone applications communication

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, rmi, wildfly-8

What are the best practices to have two applications **on the same host**, one J2EE and the other Java standalone, communicate one with the other?

More infos:

- The j2ee application will be deplyed in Wildfly AS
- The Java stand alone is a Netty NIO Server

**EDIT ONE**
Even more infos:

- The Netty server is a cardgame server that will hold the business logic for the game itself and will allow players to play synchronously one with the other (up to four players per game, up to a max amount of games allowed from my hw server resources)
- The J2ee application (deployed in Wildly) will take care of authentication&authorization
- The J2ee application will take care of the DB connection and Persistence
- The J2ee application will have to forward to the java standalone server the remote-socket-address of the authenticated player and eventually an object holding the state of that player
- The J2ee application will potentially be the one triggering the communication although for my current flow, i am in need of a full duplex communication from both ends (hence my fear about a WS or Rest, isn't it kind of asymmetrical for a full duplex communication channel?)
- The Netty server may be seen as a background task of the AS that will start it (and eventually other cardgame servers) in an attempt of pseudo horizzontal scalability

Comment: Do it whatever way you are most familiar and comfortable with. The J2EE-ness of an application does not affect how it can communicate with other applications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have one open a socket and communicate to the other.

You could do more exotic stuff, but if anything about the environment changes, it will break.  For a few ideas of "exotic stuff"

1. Write and read from named pipes
2. Set up a shared memory buffer, or two.
   etc ...

Comment: Just want to add that socket communication does not depend on Java or jee. You can communicate and integrate Java with any network capable application and the best way would not be reinventing the wheel but using http ( aka rest) or web services and not some own proprietary socket protocol.

Comment: While I am inclined to agree, HTTP typically involves a bit more than simple socket communication.  In many cases, if you want stateless processing it is the right choice; however, if you want stateful processing, the amount of stuff you need to layer on top of that stateless protocol is staggering.

Comment: yes, that's true, communication always depends on context. There is nice speech about this here http://oredev.org/2010/sessions/pragmatic-interoperability-making-java-and-net-play-well-together

Comment: @Edwin Buck , i have edited my question accordingly

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not possible to give a good implementation pattern when you are not clear/explicit about the following relevant questions:

1. Is the standalone application a background task (possibly launched
   with the container)?
2. If yes, do both J2EE and standalone have to
   share session or conversation data?
3. Who triggers the communication
   when communicating?
4. Do both applications possibly share the same back-end database?

Comment: i have edited my question accordingly

Comment: Not knowing Netty NIO I'm not sure if relevant/applicable: what about considering persistent communication via the data store?

Comment: You mean (in this case) to have the two applications share the same DB? My fear is that being Netty a NIO (Non-Blocking Input Output) server, while Database access are usually Blocking, will cause a loss of performances if the transaction is associated/invocatedBy a IO method, hence Netty will relay on JBoss for persistency. This is just a fear of mine tho, and i have nothing to prove it so far